# Finding whitespaces from a unicoded/non-english string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In my code, I need to display the name in some specified format in which each charecter should be replaced with an '*' charecter. However, I don't have to replace whitespaces.

Now since it is a japanese application, names may contain Japanese space charecters also. Can any help me with a generic way of identifying space charecters.
What I did is in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5089a331b5e7cce2f84f433ae710d187).

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'ab cb';
select IIF(LEN(LTRIM(substring(a.Name, v.number, 1))) = 0, substring(a.Name, v.number, 1), '*')
from (select @Name Name) a
join (  SELECT (1 + ones.n + ISNULL(10*tens.n, 0) + ISNULL(100*thausand.n, 0))  Number
      FROM  (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thausand(n)
  )V on v.Number <= len(a.Name);

SET @Name = N'中山　大地';
select IIF(LEN(LTRIM(substring(a.Name, v.number, 1))) = 0, substring(a.Name, v.number, 1), '*')
from (select @Name Name) a
join (  SELECT (1 + ones.n + ISNULL(10*tens.n, 0) + ISNULL(100*thausand.n, 0))  Number
      FROM  (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thausand(n)
  )V on v.Number <= len(a.Name);
```

Comment: What is a "Japanese space char" and how is it different from a "regular" space char?

Comment: @ZoharPeled : It have a different Char code. You may check it by executing : [select CAST(N' ' as VARBINARY(10)), CAST(N'　' as VARBINARY(10))]

Comment: Thanks! I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account that all characters with the space property [here](https://unicode.org/charts/collation/chart_Whitespace.html), the necessary query may look like this:

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'ab cb';
select IIF(LEN(LTRIM(substring(a.Name, v.number, 1))) = 0, substring(a.Name, v.number, 1), '*')
from (select @Name Name) a
join (  SELECT (1 + ones.n + ISNULL(10*tens.n, 0) + ISNULL(100*thausand.n, 0))  Number
      FROM  (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thausand(n)
  )V on v.Number <= len(a.Name);

SET @Name = N'中山　大地';

with
  wss as (
    select nchar(u) ws
    from(values(0x0009), (0x000A), (0x000B), (0x000C), (0x000D),
               (0x0085), (0x2028), (0x2029), (0x0020), (0x3000),
               (0x1680), (0x2000), (0x2001), (0x2002), (0x2003),
               (0x2004), (0x2005), (0x2006), (0x2008), (0x2009),
               (0x200A), (0x205F), (0x00A0), (0x2007), (0x202F)) ws(u)
  )
select IIF(LEN(LTRIM(substring(a.Name, v.number, 1))) = 0, substring(a.Name, v.number, 1), '*') replace1,
  iif(substring(a.Name, v.number, 1) in (select ws from wss), substring(a.Name, v.number, 1), '*') replace2
from (select @Name Name) a
join (  SELECT (1 + ones.n + ISNULL(10*tens.n, 0) + ISNULL(100*thausand.n, 0))  Number
      FROM  (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thausand(n)
  )V on v.Number <= len(a.Name);
```

**Output:**

```
+------------------+
| (No column name) |
+------------------+
| *                |
| *                |
|                  |
| *                |
| *                |
+------------------+

+----------+----------+
| replace1 | replace2 |
+----------+----------+
| *        | *        |
| *        | *        |
| *        | 　        |
| *        | *        |
| *        | *        |
+----------+----------+
```

Test it online with [Rextester](https://rextester.com/TGD70973).

Comment: Awesome. This one will do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in SQL2017.

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'中山　大地';

SELECT STRING_AGG(replicate('*', LEN(value)), ' ') AS obfuscated
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@name, ' ')
```

[image: obfuscated]

[STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) SQL2016

[STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) SQL2017

However for older SQL Servers versions this might be a bit more challenging.

String Split:

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'ab cd e';

SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS data_field
FROM   ( SELECT CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@Name, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS String ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
```

String Agg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ' ' + t2.data_field
         from (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS data_field
                FROM   ( SELECT CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@Name, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS String ) AS A
                       CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) t2

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
```

Comment: Sorry but this will not help me at all. String aggrigation is not the problem here, identifying the space char is. I need a way to identify all the space chars erespective of Code page etc. and your way is not even on way to that